# How To Convert A String Time Hours and Minutes to a Calendar Object Hours and Minutes without using deprecated Method in Android

Tags: android, datetime

**=>String time="18:00:00.0000000";**

```
public static Calendar getCalandarFromString(String time) {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        try {
            DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            Date date = sdf.parse(time);
            System.out.println("Date and Time: " + date);
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,date.getHours());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,date.getMinutes());
            return calendar;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return calendar;
        }

    }
```

**=>"date.getHours()" and "date.getMinutes()" is deprecated i don't want to use these two methods.**
**Any one have idea to achieve this function without deprecated methods.**

Answer (score 1):

you can just pass entire date object to calendar

```
 yourCalendarInstance.setTime(date);
```

Comment: This solution is not work because i don't have date.
Only have time in String.

Comment: But you have it
`DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); `

`Date date = sdf.parse(time);`

Comment: If problem with date string parsing you may try `new SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm.ss.fffffff");`

Answer (score 1):

You may use `String.split()` method like this
`String[] array = time.split(":");`
`int hours = array[0];`
`int minutes = array[1];`

Comment: It's not work because i have to compare this Calendar object with Current System Time object. Current time might be in 12 Hours or 24 Hours format.